# Web crawler tool that generate a list of all the anchors used on a site

Tags: tools, software, web-crawlers

I'm looking for a web crawler tool that'll go through all the anchor text on a whole web site and generate a list for me to check. I want to make sure all the anchors are really descriptive outside the context. I don't care if it's web based or a desktop based software.

Comment: "I don't care if it's web based or a desktop based software." - Are you working with Windows or Linux/UNIX operating systems on your server and desktop?

Comment: PC/Windows 7 and Mac/MacOs Lion

Answer (score 2):

You could try Xenu's Link Sleuth:

http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html